# reverse a string using recursion with java

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to write a recursion to reverse a String.This is my approach.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abc";
        String b = reverseString(str);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public static String reverseString(String a){
        if (a.isEmpty()){
            return a;
        }

        return reverseString(a.substring(1)) + a.charAt(0);
    }
```

I dont get why when it reaches the base case, where my a is already empty but I am still able to print out the reversed string.

Comment: @Kayaman removing the `if` will cause an exception as the substring from index 1 will no longer be available at some point.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question James, this code worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought that you were including the `charAt()` in the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not implementing any recursion, you just replaced two halves of a string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "abcd";

    String b = reverseString(str);
    System.out.println(b);
}

public static String reverseString(String str) {
    int p = str.length() / 2;
    if (str.length() == 1)
        return str;
    String prefix = reverseString(str.substring(p, str.length()));
    String suffix = reverseString(str.substring(0, p));

    return prefix + suffix;
}
```

Comment: Use ``` for code snippets